# Device administrator can not be deactivated

Tags: rom-flashing, bootloader, uninstallation, odin, device-administrator

I installed a security app on my Samsung phone and it blocks the device from going to Odin mode (bootloader) so I can not update the software. I can not remove this app because it is a device administrator. Also when I navigate to device administartors in Settings I can not deactivate it (deactivate button is grayed out). Can anyone help me and suggest any idea on how to get rid of this app?

Comment: If you installed from Play Store, go to play store and deactivate and uninstall

Comment: No, I installed it from APK file.

Comment: [related](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/128075/131553)- you can try those solutions

Comment: It might have become the [device owner](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#DeviceOwner).