# Uninstall Android app from Google Play website

Tags: applications, uninstallation

I have installed one of the android apps, which is for double tap to screen on/off, but this app is  misleading. Unfortunately I gave admin permission for this app, after installing this android app, My mobile screen is never showing up. But, I can hear phone rings, message tones, and everything working fine. How do I make my screen visible now??

Is there anyway to uninstall that particular app, from any website?? I'm pretty sure that, screen is not popping up because of this app. Please help me here.

Comment: Have you seen: [How to remove an app that is a persistent device administrator](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/128075/3573) You should [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/229849/edit) your post with make/model of Android phone and if possible what OS version.

Comment: Could you mention the link to the app in the comment? While we acknowledge the risk, some of us may experiment with it on the emulator/spare device to be certain. Though, AFAIK there's no way to uninstall an app from the Play Store website.